# What happens to the electricity after it is used in a CPU cycle?

Tags: cpu

After the pulse of electricity is used to complete a cycle through the CPU, what happens to it?  Is it reused in anyway?  Or does it goes straight to the ground wire?

If it is not reused, why not?

Comment: A "pulse of electricity" isn't a discrete unit that can be reused, like a lump of coal, or a rabbit.  You seem to lack even a basic understanding of what electricity is. Start with the basics, like batteries and light bulbs.

Comment: A "pulse of electricity" **is** discrete, comprising a number of discrete charges - electrons - which are quantifiable and measured in units of coulombs. The "pulse of electricity" is also quantifiable and can be measured by the amount of work it does in transporting charge, in units called "joules".

Comment: So, @Majenko, how would someone reuse a rabbit? Oh, wait, I don't wanna know. Forget I said anything...

Comment: @Ricardo Carefully. Very very carefully. And with plenty of mayonnaise.

Comment: @EMFields By not a discrete unit I mean not something you can pick up and put somewhere else. It's not an object in its own right, but a change of state of another system. Unless you fancy sending me a tin of electric pulses... to have with my rabbit?

Comment: @Majenko: Well, then, neither is the lump of coal discrete, once it's used, so your daffynition needs a little work. ;)

Comment: @EMFields That depends on a) what you use it for initially, and b) what you want to use it for afterwards.  Coal ashes are great for gritting the path in winter.

Comment: @Majenko: And a pulse of electricity, after it's used, can be used to melt the snow along the path.

Comment: @EMFields Only if it's finely GND.

Comment: @Majenkko: You'll get no resistance from me on that one! Thanks for the chuckle! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question can not be answered because "electricity" is not a physical quantity.  There is no such thing as *a pulse of electricity*.  What units would you propose to measure this "electricity" in?

This is like asking how much weather it takes to make a foot of snow.  The whole question simply makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'll go read up on the basics as suggested

Comment: "How much weather it takes..." Good analogy, Olin :)

Answer (score 5):

If one imagines the switching elements in a processor or other such device as being buckets, it's possible to switch a bucket to a "full" state by letting water flow from the supply into the bucket, or switch a bucket to an "empty" state by letting water flow from the bucket into a catch-basin.  The water is neither created nor destroyed, but it will end up with less energy than it had before it was used to fill a bucket and then subsequently drained.  In order for the water to be able to fill buckets again, some sort of external power source must lift it up again, since in the absence of a direct motivating force, water will only flow from an area of higher pressure/elevation to an area of lower pressure.

Likewise, switching a logic gate will entail the gate either allowing current to flow from one supply rail into the gate, or from the gate to the other supply rail.  Each time a gate switches low then high then low, or vice versa, the amount of charge required to fill or empty it will end up being allowed to flow from one supply rail to the other; the electrons will have less energy afterward than before, so an external source of energy will be needed to make them repeat the trip.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, after it does its job, it dissipates its remaining energy as heat and disappears as an entity.